# How to change "Use In Search Results Layered Navigation" option of attributes?

Tags: attributes, search, option

So I created a custom attribute called 'weight'.

When I search for a product in the Frontend, it shows 'Weight' in the Search Result options sidebar because I left "Use In Search Results Layered Navigation" to "Yes".

What's worse is that the unit for weight is set to dollars.

I just want to disable weight in the search options sidebar. But I can't. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PvRyv.png).

Comment: How did you solve this? I have the same issue.